# Does Apple accept code containing check for UITableViewWrapperView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using following code to check if there is tap happened on my `viewcontroller.view`.
(PS: I have added tap `gesturerecognizer` for that)

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    NSLog(@"\n Clicked view is of type %@",touch.view.class);
    if ([touch.view isMemberOfClass:[self class]] || [NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewWrapperView"])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

As my `viewcontroller.view` contains `TableView` with minimal rows and some other view like text field etc, I always get `UITableViewWrapperView` printed in above `NSLOG` , when I tap between the gap between table view (with few rows) and my text field at bottom.
This might be because, frame of my tableview is large enough to accomodate touch point, though there are few cells visible

Above code is working perfect to dismiss keyboard for such a tap.
I am just worried if Apple approves such code check containing `UITableViewWrapperView`.

~Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to use `UITableView` instead, it should be the next responder. The wrapper view has been recently added and it might be silently removed at any feature iOs version, your code isn't safe or "perfectly working" for that matter.

Comment: So your aim is to dismiss a keyboard when the user taps on the table view but doesn't actually hit a row on the table? Ask that question rather than asking about 'private' classes

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:nil];
CGPoint convertedPointWRTMainView = [self.view convertPoint:touchPoint fromView:nil];
CGPoint convertedPointWRTTouchView =  [YourTableViewReference convertPoint:touchPoint fromView:nil];
BOOL shouldReturnTouch = [YourTableViewReference pointInside:convertedPointWRTTouchView withEvent:nil];
  shouldReturnTouch =  shouldReturnTouch || [self.view pointInside:convertedPointWRTMainView withEvent:nil];

if(shouldReturnTouch) {
return YES;
}
return NO;
```

This Code will let you know if the touched point using tap gesture is within your tableview. So rather than using "UITableViewWrapperView" hardcoded check if the touch lies within the tableview and also check if tap is in the main view.
try this will work for iOS 6 and 7

Comment: What is this? How on earth does this answer the question? Lack of any explanation will get you down votes here. -1

Comment: @SatyamRaikar Just because you disagree with a comment doesn't mean that you have to be abusive about it.

Comment: @SatyamRaikar The idea of this site is some asks a question, users provide answers that have explanations, future users who are experiencing an issue simpler if not the same can review the answers reading the explanation and can try an implement the answer. If a new user comes along and has the same issue as the OP and looks at your answer they will not have a clue what is going on here, I like to think I am an experienced developer and I don't have a clue how your answer answers the OPs question. So my downvote is valid, I don't need to be the OP to downvote.

Comment: @SatyamRaikar There also doesn't need to be anything wrong with the code but if it doesn't explain itself then like your answer doesn't I can downvote. This is how the site works, if you don't like it don't use it, it's that simple. If the user knew what was going on then they wouldn't be asking the question in the first place, so clearly they don't. And offensive language like that isn't welcome here and is just going to get you banned from using the site. I have flagged your comment as abusive, like I say if you don't like the way this works then stop using this site.

Comment: @SatyamRaikar you used `"@sshole "SAILOR"` that is clearly being abusive. If you provide an explanation that explains your answer then I will be more than happy to remove my downvote, but since you have insulted me I very much don't really want to, but that is also not how this works if you provide an explanation that is good then the downvote will go. And just so you know I know what your code is doing I just don't understand how it solves the OPs issue, that is also why you need the explanation.

Comment: @SatyamRaikar you clearly said `"@sshole "SAILOR""` which you were clearly referring to the downvoter (Myself) so you were clearly being abusive to myself. Abusive language like this, any language like this isn't welcome here. Please don't try and say you weren't being abusive as your comment is still there, it is perfectly clear you were being abusive and for this reason I have flagged it for moderator attention, and even if you delete it now they will still see the comment.

Comment: As promised I have removed my -1, thank you for adding the explanation.